# Phonegap/Cordova BUILD FAILED ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, cmd

I am very new to phonegap and today I tried to launch an angular.js app using phonegap. The sample beginner app was fine but once I deleted all the files in www folder and replaced them with anulgar.js App everything stopped working. (NOTE: I DID include the cordova.js file). This is the error I get in the cmd when I try to type `cordova build android` :

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occur
red while executing this line:
C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOf
BoundsException: 1
        at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.parseDependencyFile(DependencyGraph.j
ava:180)
        at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.<init>(DependencyGraph.java:54)
        at com.android.ant.SingleDependencyTask.initDependencies(SingleDependenc
yTask.java:87)
        at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:509)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.jav
a:396)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 7 seconds
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,F:\WorkSpace\BikeDic
e\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: F:\WorkSpace\BikeDice\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed
 with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

PS: I am not using node.js or any server-side-technology. As far as I understood I don't need to in order to use angular.js with phonegap.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem which makes no sense because I didn't touch anything and it was working minutes ago...

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the ant-build and ant-gen folders from your project and rebuilding it.